# Tidycensus Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: r, tidyverse, census, tidycensus

I'm trying to load census data but every time I use the `get_decennial` my code throws an error.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)

vars <- c(tot_hh = "H001001",
         tot_rural_hh = "H002005",
         tot_rent_hh = "H004004",
         avg_hh_size = "H012001",
         tot_pop = "P003001",
         nh_white_pop = "P005003",
         nh_black_pop = "P005004",
         nh_asian_pop = "P005006",
         hispanic_pop = "P005010",
         med_age = "P013001")

SD_tracts <- get_decennial(geography = "tract", variables = vars,
                           state = "CA", county = "San Diego",
                           output = "wide")
```

I've defined several variables and I'm trying to call this data but every time I do I get this error message:

> `Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character".`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You appear not to have called census_api_key() before get_decennial(). Could that be an explanation?

Comment: Try updating your packages; your code runs fine for me.  I'd recommend updating tidycensus and dplyr at first glance, then trying again.